# Problema con retorno de consulta en vista, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

En mi caso poseo una consulta que planteo configurar con sql directo, se que no es algo practivo, pero debido a las circuntacias debo hacerlo asi por ahora.

```
$data = DB::select('select usuario_ad, count(usuario_ad) from usuarios where 
 usuario_ad in (select username from users where users.refer="Thor" union 
  select "Thor") group by (usuario_ad)');

  return view('Usuario.reportes')->with(["data" => $data, "conteodos" => 
   $conteodos]);
```

Al retornar el resultado de la consulta en vista, tengo este error.

"Call to a member function count() on array"

especificamente en esta linea de mi vista.

```
<?php if($data->count()): ?>
```

Este es el fragmento del html

```
  <th>Usuario</th>
     </thead>
         <tbody>  
            @if($data->count())
               @foreach($data as $dat)
                 <tr>
                 <td>{{$dat->usuario_ad}}</td>
                 </tr>
                @endforeach  
                @else
                <tr>
               <td colspan="8">No hay registro !!</td>
              </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debería consulta mejor las funciones de PHP, la función de count() se utiliza de la siguiente forma en php, lo que esta haciendo es utilizar la sintaxis de las consulta de Laravel en la vista

```
$datas=array(
  "0"=>array("marcos","manzana"),
  "1"=>array("saavedra","uva")
);
  // con php
if(count($pilotos)){
   echo "si hay datos";
}else{
   echo "no hay datos";
}

//blade en laravel
 @if(count($pilotos))
       echo "si hay datos";
 @else
       echo "no hay datos";
 @endif
```

Comment: Lo que el OP intenta hacer es utilizar la sintaxis de las colecciones de Laravel, lo cual no es incorrecto, simplemente no tiene una colección por lo visto. Pareciera estar más confundido quien responde.